# MaxScript - Spline Smooth?

Tags: maxscript

I tried to make this script in 3dsmax 2017 using listener but it does not record just that action for spline - smooth (like in the screenshot).

When I select subobject level - Vertex, and select all, then I right click and choose smooth, , I got result I need.
I need to make it using script because I have a number of splines that need to be smooth.
any help appreciated.

```
select $Line001
subobjectLevel = 1
modPanel.setCurrentObject $.baseObject
```

I tried couple of script that I find online but they don't work in 3dsmax 2017.
So if you have solution example that work in **3dsmax 2017**.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0r0US.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [SplineShape](http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/16/ENU/MAXScript-Help/index.html?url=files/GUID-6C6A35EB-DD5F-40C1-9869-0938849F6842.htm,topicNumber=d30e380960) topic in the maxscript reference.

```
for spline = 1 to numSplines $
    where (selectedKnots = getKnotSelection $ spline).count > 0 do
        for knot in selectedKnots do setKnotType $ spline knot #smooth

updateShape $
```